# how does the HttpServletResponse reach the same browser window from where request was made

Tags: java, servlets

How does HttpServletResponse reach the same browser window from where request was made. Is it the servlet container that keeps a track of which browser window the request was made from or this information is stored in response object. Any information related to this would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Via TCP/IP. A TCP connection. Off topic for this site.